# Upgrading to rails 4.2, Model Concerns now give LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Concerns::blahblah

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I wrote a generator that creates a concern for the user to include in their model.  It works correctly on Rails 4.1.8, but on Rails 4.2.0, I get this message:

```
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Concerns::NameSearch.
```

`NameSearch` is the concern module the generator creates, `app/models/concerns/name_search.rb`:

```
module NameSearch
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    ...
  end

  module ClassMethods
    ...
  end

private
  ...
end
```

And in the model I simply `include NameSearch`.  I get the error when I run a rake task (a migration) after including the concern.  The application actually runs correctly, it's just the rake task that throws the error.  And the rake task also seems to have done it's job, but throws this error at the end.
Again, this worked fine in 4.1.8, but not in 4.2.0.  Any idea what changed?

Comment: Strange. That should work. Can you edit your question to show the output from `puts Rails.application.config.eager_load_paths` when run inside `rails console`?

Comment: `vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
irb(main):001:0> Rails.application.config.eager_load_paths
=> ["/vagrant/app/assets", "/vagrant/app/controllers", "/vagrant/app/helpers", "/vagrant/app/mailers", "/vagrant/app/models", "/vagrant/app/controllers/concerns", "/vagrant/app/models/concerns"]
irb(main):002:0> 
`

Comment: And I get the same result with 4.1.8, btw.

Comment: @Daiku: any luck with solving this?

Comment: @santuxus:  It was actually an error in a gem I was using in my concern.  It was this:  https://github.com/cequel/cequel/commit/4ab1978d13b842ffa9982be08b5342614884ff50

Comment: @Daiku: Whooo! Thank you! I had it because of cequel too!

Comment: And I see Mat tagged it and released it.  Thanks for prodding him!

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the right Ruby constant lookup convention (adding **Concerns::** to the module):

*app/models/concerns/name_search.rb*

```
module Concerns::NameSearch
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    ...
  end

  module ClassMethods
    ...
  end

private
  ...
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Add (**require 'active_support/concern'**) in app/models/concerns/name_search.rb

for example:

require 'active_support/concern'

module NameSearch

```
   #codes
```

end